# Joomla 3.10.x upgrade with new Pre-Update check

Tags: upgrade

upgrading one of my sites from Joomla 3.9.x to Joomla 10.1.x and have been introduced to the new pre-update check.
It tells me to be patient while I wait for the pre-check to complete (thi is my largest site).

I had my session time set to 15mins. I tried 3 times and it timed out before updating. I then set the session time to 40mins and STILL the prescheck did not finished /did not happen.

I tried to do a live update; ticked the 'Do you wish to ignore the warnings about potentially incompatible plugins and to proceed with the upgrade?' message but the install the update button does not work.
Not certain where to go next.

https://docs.joomla.org/Pre-Update_Check  This document does not describe the live update feature and I have not got to the stage of needing to know what all the pre-check messages mean becuase it won't finish the pre-check.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you open your browser console, try the pre-update check again, and check for any errors?

Comment: Nice @Jenny -- congrats on posting your first question.  It all gets easier from here!

Comment: I am a bit of a nuffer Lodder. I don't know what you mean, sorry. 
I donwloaded the zip package. Can I do it that way, rather than the joomla installer?

Comment: I would try, as @Lodder suggested, to find the reason for the problem. How to open the Browser Console is described on Wikipedia for the different browsers. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools

Comment: @JennyMcWilliam For comparison I performed a pre-update check on a site with a lot of extension, a lot more than you have on your sites, and it only ran for not quite 2 minutes so don't waste your time waiting for 40 minutes as you try to solve this issue..

Comment: Sorry I am slow on this. Still unresolved. ANother website went thorugh SO easily. If I click the upload and update tab, this si the message I get "The PHP temporary folder is the folder that PHP uses to store an uploaded file before Joomla can access this file. Whilst the folder not being set isn't always a problem, if you are having issues with manifest files not being detected or uploaded files not being detected, setting this in your php.ini file might fix the issue." is this a nomral message to receive?